# How can we efficiently store objects using stl containers? (viz. for searching based on values of their fields)

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have objects of something like this:

```
struct stStudents 
{
    int roll_number; // Can be think as unique key
    std::string name;
    // There could be more fields here
}
```

I need to store these objects using stl containers in such a way that I should be able to search them as fast as possible based on field(s) e.g `roll_number` or `name` (or both) in above example.

**What I already tried/thought of:**

1. As plain as it can get, if I simply store them in `std::vector` (and probably by using `std::find_if`) searching will be O(n).
2. With `std::set` and `std::map` it would take O(log N), but for that however overloaded comparison operator of the object needs to be based on particular field (or may be set of fields by using `std::tie`)
3. Having various `std::unordered_set` of pointers (inside struct) to those objects. And define comparison operator in the struct based on search criteria (just like we define multiple indices in database). This will be O(1) search but limited to predefined search criteria.

**Question:**

How are these approaches and what are other better alternatives can we think of?

Comment: What is the *real* problem you try to solve? Why do you need this to be "efficient"? What is your definition of "efficient"? And have you measured, profiled and benchmarked that searching using e.g. vectors and `std::find_if` is not "good enough" (which almost always *is* good enough)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude.. not really profiled. It is currently at PoC level. So while designing just making sure to start with most efficient data structure. Yes vectors and `std::find_if` could be best candidate, so just looking for validations, in that case.

Comment: You forgot to define one property that is also important: is the `roll_number` unique? And: is the `name` unique? Depending on the answer to that question you may end up with `std::multimap`, `std::multiset` and `std::copy_if` instead.

Comment: @user23573 valid point. thanks. will update question accordingly

Comment: @Atul "not really profiled" premature optimization...

Comment: [boost::multi_index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) might interest you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map` and `set` are the best when in comes to searching.
So if we really want only speed in Searching then make maps for both the name and roll.
But we are giving up on Space efficiency.

Sample Code :
Written in Visual Studio 2012

both `search` functions could attain O(log(N)).

```
typedef struct _tagStudent
{
    int m_nRoll;
    std::string m_strName;
    _tagStudent(): m_nRoll(0)
    {}
    _tagStudent( int nRoll, std::string strName): m_nRoll( nRoll ), 
        m_strName(strName)
    {}
    bool operator<( _tagStudent x) const
    {
        return x.m_nRoll > m_nRoll;
    }
}Student;

class Students
{
    std::map< int, Student > m_mapStudent;
    std::map< std::string, std::set<Student> > m_mapStudentIndexName;
public:
    Students();
    ~Students();
    //Adding students Index
    void Add( const Student & );
    //Searching Students by Roll
    Student Search( const int& ) const;
    //Searching Students by Name
    std::set<Student> Search( const std::string&) const;
};


Students::Students()
{}
Students::~Students()
{}
void Students::Add( const Student& oStudent )
{
    m_mapStudent[oStudent.m_nRoll] = oStudent;
    m_mapStudentIndexName[oStudent.m_strName].insert(oStudent);
}

Student Students::Search( const int& nRoll ) const
{
    if( m_mapStudent.find( nRoll ) != m_mapStudent.end() )
    {
        return m_mapStudent.at( nRoll );
    }
    return Student();
}
std::set<Student> Students::Search( const std::string& strName) const
{
    std::set<Student> oStudents;
    if( m_mapStudentIndexName.find( strName ) != m_mapStudentIndexName.end() )
    {
        return m_mapStudentIndexName.at(strName);
    }
    return std::set<Student>();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    Students oStudents;
    oStudents.Add( Student(1, "Tom") );
    oStudents.Add( Student(2, "Jerry") );
    oStudents.Add( Student(15, "Jerry") );
    oStudents.Add( Student(3, "Tim") );

    auto search1 = oStudents.Search( 1 );
    auto search3 = oStudents.Search( "Jerry" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "`Map` and `set` are the best when in comes to searching." Define "best". Most convenient interfaces, maybe, but certainly not fastest.

Comment: Yep. If you care about performance, you always use either `std::vector<>`, `std::unordered_set<>`, or `std::unordered_map<>`. If you want a stack, you use `std::vector<>`, if you don't care about order, you use `std::vector<>`. There are very few cases where a linked list makes sense from a performance perspective, and the ordered `std::set<>` and `std::map<>` are just too slow compared to their unordered counterparts. It's basically: If an `std::vector<>` does the trick, use it.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes and thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You must not have `typedef` to a C++ type. Typedef is for C compiler, the overloaded operator is for C++!

Comment: @Ajay it's wrong to say you "must not" have that. It's valid C++, it's just dumb and pointless.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I didn't say it won't compile, but just advised that it must not have (shouldn't have is lighter). I have seen a lot of template code buried under "typedef'ed" classes! Hence, I hate it.

Comment: @f1r361rd when you override operator `<` to compare `m_nRoll` you cannot get  O(log(N)) when searching `m_strName`. It will be O(n) there.

Comment: @Atul Only reason why `Operator<` is overloaded is for the `set<Students>`. It has nothing to do with both the maps which we use for searching.